# Data table not auto resizing when populate adjacent column header

Tags: excel

When I use tables in Excel and add text to the first row after last column of table, the table auto changes to include new header. I have a colleague that when repeats same steps doesn't get the table auto resizing. We have been through Options menu in excel and verified that every stetting is exactly the same.
Example steps;
use "Format as table" to format table.
Table is in columns A:D.
Add a new header in E1, table automatically expands to 5 columns from 4.

This is what should happen and what i experience. Why would it not work and what is worth checking to make this happen.

TIA